# How to get checkbox values from another form with asp .net MVC4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

Here is a simplified example. My first form :

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action1", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input id="cb" type="checkbox" value="true" name="MyCheckBox" />
        <label for="cb">Check this out</label>
    }
```

And late in the same view, another form :

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action2", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
    }
```

How to efficiently get the value (checked or not) of this checkbox, in the action Action2 in MyController ?

Comment: Try wrapping the whole thing in Form1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser don't send values from another form in requests.
The only way to do it is to handle `onsubmit` event with js/jquery, add value to form and submit it with js.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, i'll try this or may be try to create an unique form. Thanks.